# Window scroll certain div smoothly up and down

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to move up and down the certain div with window scroll up and down like squarespace site?

https://www.squarespace.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean like the navigation bar?

Simply add the `position` property, with the value `fixed` to the **CSS** of the element you intend to stay fixed to the screen.

For example:

```
.navbar{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px; // will always stay at the top of the page
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I mean this kind of div part that moves up and down by window scrolling[image]